# C - I Think i'm Doing a realloc wrong

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm doing some exercise in preparation for my test and in one of those I have to remove duplicated int values from an array:

```
int *eliminaDup(int *vect, int dim, int *dim_nodup){
    int i = 0, newDim = 0, found = 0, j = 0;
    int *tmpArr = malloc(dim * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        j = 0; found = 0;
        while(j < newDim && !found){
            if(vect[i] == tmpArr[j])
                found = 1;
            j++;
        }
        if(!found){
            tmpArr[newDim] = vect[i];
            newDim++;
        }
    }
    *dim_nodup = newDim;
    return (realloc(tmpArr, newDim * sizeof(int)));
}
```

And in the main method is called this way:

```
nodup=eliminaDup(input,dim,&dim_nodup);
printf("Print of the new Array: (%d values)\n", dim_nodup);
for (i=0; i<dim_nodup; i++){
    printf("%d\n",nodup[i]);
}
```

But when I try to execute the code, [This happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fPkL.png):

ARRAY GIVEN IN INPUT:

```
 [1;2]
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
2
```

OUTPUT EXPECTED:

```
1
2

...other output from the code...
```

and as you can see from the screen, the code should go on and print other stuff.

I made some tries and i saw that the code "lock" exactly after the print, but it never came out from the for.

...Why? I'm banging my head on the keyboard.

EDIT: Complete program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *leggiInput(int *dim);
int *eliminaDup(int *vect, int dim, int *dim_nodup);
int ugualeASomma(int *vect,int dim);
int *maggioreDeiSuccessivi(int *vect, int dim);

int main()
{
    int *input, *nodup, *results;
    int dim, dim_nodup, i;

    //Legge l'input
    input=leggiInput(&dim);
    printf("Stampa dei valori in input: (%d valori)\n", dim);
    for (i=0; i<dim; i++)
        printf("%d\n",input[i]);

    //Elimina i duplicati
    nodup=eliminaDup(input,dim,&dim_nodup);
    printf("Stampa dei valori senza duplicati: (%d valori)\n", dim_nodup);
    for (i=0; i<dim_nodup; i++){
        printf("%d\n",nodup[i]);
    }
    //Esegue ugualeASomma
    printf("Risultato di ugualeASomma: %d\n", ugualeASomma(nodup,dim_nodup));

    //Esegue maggioreDeiSuccessivi
    results=maggioreDeiSuccessivi(nodup,dim_nodup);
    printf("Risultato maggioreDeiSuccessivi:\n");
    for(i=0; i<dim_nodup; i++)
        printf("%d\n",results[i]);

    return 0;
}

int *leggiInput(int *dim){
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int)); 
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    *dim = n;
    return arr;
}

int *eliminaDup(int *vect, int dim, int *dim_nodup){
    int i = 0, newDim = 0, trovato = 0, j = 0;
    int *tmpArr = malloc(dim * sizeof(int));
    while(i < dim){
        j = 0; trovato = 0;
        while(j < newDim && !trovato){
            if(vect[i] == tmpArr[j])
                trovato = 1;
            j++;
        }
        if(!trovato){
            tmpArr[newDim] = vect[i];
            newDim++;
        }
    i++;
    }
    *dim_nodup = newDim;
    return (realloc(tmpArr, newDim * sizeof(int)));
}

int ugualeASomma(int *vect, int dim){
    int somma = 0, i = 0, j, trovato = 0;

    while(i < dim)
        somma += vect[i];
    while(i < dim){
        if(vect[i] == somma - vect[i])
            trovato = 1;
    }

    return trovato;
}

int *maggioreDeiSuccessivi(int *vect, int dim){
    int i = 0, j, trovato;
    while(i < dim){
        j = i+1; trovato = 0;       
        while(j < dim && !trovato){
            if(vect[i] <= vect[j])
                trovato = 1;
            else
                j++;        
        }

        if(trovato) vect[i] = 0;
        else vect[i] = 1;
        i++;                
    }

    return vect;
}
```

EDIT: Solved in comments changing malloc to calloc.

Comment: Perhaps using a for loop instead of `while(i < dim){` would make the code more readable

Comment: You should [edit] your post to include the output in the question instead of linking to a screenshot

Comment: One problem with your code is that it might leak memory.

Comment: BTW, there's a a faster algorithm how to find duplicated: sort the input first.

Comment: Please read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then add the missing information.

Comment: @kfx I have to print the new array in the same order of which I read the input.

Comment: Alyways check the result of `malloc` & friends.

Comment: Can you post a complete compilable program? It looks like the error is somewhere else, e.g. you could have an infinite loop in `ugualeASomma`.

Comment: A debugger saves you from a lot of head banging ;-).

Comment: `vect[i] == tmpArr[j]` doesn't make sense: `tmpArr` is uninitialized memory, `tmpArr[j]` _might_ contain values that are in `vect`. If you're going to keep this code, I'd suggest you use `calloc` instead

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That's it! Thanks!
I thought that when entering the "If" condition the array would be already populated, thanks a lot!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Funny. I'd think that the comparison is only performed for initialized elements in tmpArr (because the index j goes only to  newDim-1 which is initially 0 and is only incremented for "not found" numbers used to initialize tmpArr).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: I started typing an answer, and as I tried to explain why `calloc` would be a better fit, I came to the same conclusion. `calloc` shouldn't really make a difference.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem So why with calloc the code works?

Answer (score 2):

When realloc fails it returns NULL so you should check this and return tmpArr instead:

```
int* p = realloc(tmpArr, newDim * sizeof(int));
return p != NULL ? p : tmpArr;
```

it is good practice to initialize all declared variables, even if they will be initialized later. You may later forget about it and assume it is initialized as the function grows.

You have an infinite loop here

```
int ugualeASomma(int *vect, int dim){
    int somma = 0, i = 0, j, trovato = 0;

    while(i < dim)
        somma += vect[i];
    while(i < dim){
        if(vect[i] == somma - vect[i])
            trovato = 1;
    }

    return trovato;
}
```

i is never incremented

Comment: That's why we've `for`.

Comment: Yeah, that's another mistake, but it's not THE mistake...
Now i is incremented, but the code doesn't even enter in the second function, it got stuck in the printf before

Comment: @Marvin verify the values you read in using scanf, personally I find it better to use fgets and then sscanf to retrieve the values since otherwise some character may be left in the buffer causing subsequent scanfs to fail. it always good to check return value of scanf

Answer (score 0):

I would say Anders Karlsson has a good point. This works fine for me:

```
int ugualeASomma(int *vect, int dim){
    int somma = 0, i = 0, j, trovato = 0;

    while(i < dim)
    {
        somma += vect[i];
        if(vect[i] == somma - vect[i])
            trovato = 1;
        i++;
    }

    return trovato;
}
```